# Web browser automatisation (Robor)

Tags: c#, scala, browser, automation, awesomium

Could anyone please advise me what is the best framework/library for web browser automatisation? The task is to open web browsers page, sign in, perform some long searches, and save gathered information to excel. Now I'm using IE references in C#, but at work I could use only IE8. If I've upgraded it to IE9, but some scripts on target sites started working with errors.

I tried to use awesomium, but I couldn't parse page with help of it, as I understand. Are there any variants to do this with high speed? Size of libs - doesn't matter.

If there are any solutions compatible with Scala it would be great.

Comment: Take a look at [selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/). It has build-in support for both C# and Java (and thus for Scala too)

Answer (score 0):

As om-nom-nom hinted already, your best bet is probably a webdriver implementation like [selenium webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp). It has bindings for c# and java and can use IE, FF, Chrome, phantomjs (great if you want to go headless) and others.

Note that it might be not the best idea to do also the gathering of information directly with the webdriver, especially if the site content is changing fast. In such cases it might be useful to save the html page source with webdriver and then switch to some more efficient library for static content, like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).